# What is the shortcut key to the main search box in Trello?

Tags: trello

What is the shortcut key to the main search box? In some other applications (Gmail, Pivotal) it is `/`.

Comment: You checked the [help page regarding shortcuts](https://trello.com/shortcuts), right?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently a shortcut.